# Prevent content from breaking up when going to next line

Tags: css

I have a problem here and the solution **cannot use flexbox** as this had mobile / browser problems (despite it being my initial way of doing this). I want the content to not break up when going to the next line. If you shrink you browser window when running this code, I want it to:

1)The icons to be next to the text

2)Some containers (yellow/red) to go to the next line if not enough room is there

Using overflow or `white-space: nowrap` doesn't seem to do it. Am I doing something daft here? Sorry but I'm used to using flexbox for this!

```css
.nci {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 30px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.ncw-2 {
  font-size: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #ddf3ff !important;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.ncw-2>div {
  width: 23%;
  background: yellow !important;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.ncw-2>div:last-of-type {
  background: red !important;
  width: 31%;
}

.ncw-2>div>span {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  color: #3acaff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ncw-2">
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg" alt="Phone" class="nci"></a>
    <span>93849 294827</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg" alt="Facebook" class="nci"></a>
    <span>somerandomtext</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg" alt="Twitter" class="nci"></a>
    <span>@someraodnotext</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg" alt="Email" class="nci"></a>
    <span>some@randometextewtw.com</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the icons and text on the same line all the time? At smaller sizes when there is not enough room what do you want to happen?

Comment: sorry i meant in their own divs i want the icons and text on the same line

Comment: if they arent in the same div and its too tight i want them to drop to the next line

Comment: You may need to add media queries for this layout...

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes in your css also for small screen set the width of items to `50%` using media query.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.nci {
  width: 30px;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}

.ncw-2 {
  font-size: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #ddf3ff !important;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.ncw-2>div {
  width: 25%;
  background: yellow !important;
  float: left;
}

.ncw-2>div:last-of-type {
  background: red !important;
}

.ncw-2>div>span {
  display: block;
  color: #3acaff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 7px;
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 35px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ncw-2>div>a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 35px;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .ncw-2>div {
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="ncw-2">
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg" alt="Phone" class="nci"></a>
    <span>93849 294827</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg" alt="Facebook" class="nci"></a>
    <span>somerandomtext</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg" alt="Twitter" class="nci"></a>
    <span>@someraodnotext</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg" alt="Email" class="nci"></a>
    <span>some@randometextewtw.com</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @user8758206 added the float solution for you... Check Updated answer above

Comment: thanks a lot, but just one thing, if you view your solution on full width and then start shrinkin gthe browser, the red div at one point has the logo above its text, rather than beside this. How is this fixed?

Comment: @user8758206 did some changes in css. Check Updated answer above!

Answer (score 1):

You need first remove `float:left` from `.ncw-2>div>span`, so that the `white-space:nowrap` on the container can actual work.

Then, use media queries for wrapping layouts, e.g.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .ncw-2>div:nth-child(n) {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .ncw-2>div:nth-child(n) {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

The `:nth-child(n)` there was just for overriding the previous `:last-of-type`.

**[codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QaoxNW?editors=1100)**